# How to make a boarding screen be viewed only by new users?

Tags: flutter

can someone please help me how to make an onboarding screen after a custom splash screen be viewed only once by new users as it is very annoying to be viewed every time?
splashscreen and main codes are added below , a gif which is loaded for 3 seconds and then goes to boarding screen

My main code where it has its routes is attached below.

```
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  BusApp.sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(BusApp.sharedPreferences
        .getString('users'));
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      child: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CalculateRent()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CardChanger()),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, // Disables the debug ribbon
            home:
            SplashScreen(), // Shows splash screen as the first screen
            routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
              '/Intro_Slider': (BuildContext context) => new Boarding(),
              '/Navig': (BuildContext context) => new Navig(),
              '/Wrapper': (BuildContext context) => new Wrapper(),
              '/Home': (BuildContext context) => new Home(),
              '/Settings': (BuildContext context) => new Settings(),
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Splash Screen code :

```
class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  startTime() async {
    var _duration = new Duration(seconds: 3);
    return new Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Intro_Slider');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTime();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: new Image.asset('assets/images/splashscreen/bus.gif'),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(45.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "MoBis",
                    style: GoogleFonts.fredokaOne(
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a flag somewhere that the user has already seen the onboarding screen. For example, you can store that flag in your shared preferences.

Then when you would navigate after the splash screen you check this flag and depending on its value you go to the onboard or the home screen.

Something like this:

```
 void navigationPage() {
    if (BusApp.sharedPreferences.getBool('seenIntro')) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Home');
    } else {
      BusApp.sharedPreferences.setBool('seenIntro', true);
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Intro_Slider');
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to show us what's inside your SplashScreen class.

Comment: it is struck on the splashscreen

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using shared pref. You can save a Boolean key 'isNewUser'. Show the onboarding screen if true else show HomeScreen. 
And When show onboarding screen also update the isNewUser = false.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save a boolean in your shared_preferences when user views the intro page for the first time. And you've to check for that bool in your splash screen and based on that you've to navigate to corresponding screens.

**Splash Screen:**

```
void navigationPage() {
   var isExistingUser = BusApp.sharedPreferences.getBool('isExistingUser');
   if (isExistingUser == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Intro_Slider');
   } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/Home');
   }
}
```

**Intro Page:**

Set the boolean to true, when user finish viewing the intro slider.

```
BusApp.sharedPreferences.setBool('isExistingUser', true);
```

Comment: can you please help me by team viewer or what please its not good

Comment: @KissoonHarshad Please tell me, what is the issue you are facing, I can help you

Comment: it is not rrecognising let

Comment: @KissoonHarshad: It's my mistake. Updated the answer, changed that to var

Comment: @KissoonHarshad In your intro-slider probably you'll have a button to navigate to home page right ? Add that code in the button click

Comment: actually it goes on login page when i click on a button get started and ski button goes on the last creen of the boarding screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211709/discussion-between-midhun-mp-and-kissoon-harshad).

Comment: the error of sign out comes when the user has booked some thing